# High acceleration and dying when brake is pressed

Tags: rpm, acceleration

I have a 2003 Ford Taurus its been good, only needed a new starter and new brakes besides the standard service in the 6-7 yrs since I got it.

TL;DR:

1. High RPM in idle, need to ride brake to keep speed under control (anything I can do 'bout that?).
2. Dying
3. At least one bad spark plug.
4. With all these problems and lots of trips to the mechanic but still acting up would it make sense to get a "new used" car?

Then 7 Jan 2016 hit. Since then it has been in the shop 5 times. Once towed and once it died on top of the hill and I managed to coast in. The others I drove in. Fixed everytime.

Then 2 weeks ago it died when I shifted into park. Took it in they said it was the idler however its spelled. $93.04 dollars ok good. Ever since then its had power I mean like 2000 RPM in park, 2800-3000 RPM when in drive ok so not that high but remember this is a stock Taurus with no mods. When I come to a stop sign/light and put my foot on the brake I can feel it pulling well not moving but its like I have to push down hard just to keep it from moving. Once I let up I am gone. Also its quickly accelerates to about 50 mph and then slowly climbs that is if its going uphill, downhill is another story all without my foot on the gas.

I don't like that much power due to me living in Arkansas which has some sorry excuses for roads that have 90 degree curves on CLIFFS. Oh and I have to pass though a 25 mph school zone coming from work.

Then it died on me in drive luckily I was in a parking lot with my foot on the brake for about 3 minutes. Then a few days later I tried to start it and it would not start. The next day I tried it again and it started no problem. Took it to the shop they looked it for about 35 mins and said they didn't know what was wrong with it.

Today i looked at it and found a spark plug burned out. So i am thinking thats one problem but I don't know. I am thinking about getting another cause one problem after the other but it will have to be used.

Comment: When they replaced the Idle Air Control Valve did they reset the Keep Alive Memory? You can try disconnecting the battery cables for a few hours and see if the idle returns to normal.

Comment: See my answer for idling issues on a Ford....http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/29025/16882

Comment: Did you get this resolved?